# How to make Gnuplot use predefined colors for each bar (color not from data file)

Tags: gnuplot

Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63699595/1140754 I defined an auxiliary `myLinecolor(i) = word(LINECOLORS,i)` to use different collors for each bar, which corresponds to the value of a row in the input data file.

Yet, which argument should I pass to `myLinecolor()` regarding the bar index (i.e. row in data file) being painted?

Passing `myLinecolor(variable)` gives error `internal error : non-INTGR argument`

```
LINECOLORS = 'red green blue yellow brown gray turquoise'
myLinecolor(i) = word(LINECOLORS,i)
set output 'results.svg'

# using xval:ydata:box_width:color_index:xtic_labels
#       0:5:(0.8):0:xtic(1)
# xval        0- each row
# ydata       5 - value of column 5
# box_width   0.8
# color_index 0 - same as the number of the row
# xtic_labels xtic(1) - value of column 1

plot 'results.csv' every ::1 using 0:5:(0.8):0:xtic(1) with boxes lc rgb myLinecolor(variable)
```

e.g. I would like bar1=red, bar2=green, ..., bar7=turquoise

Comment: It's not fully clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to plot multiple columns with the colors defined in your list? e.g. column2=red, column3=green, ..., column8=turquoise?

Comment: Exactly. I will update op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with a bar chart where every bar has a different color as defined in a string with color hex-codes. You could also use an array.

**Script:**

```
### bar chart with colors defined in string
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A    1.1
B    6.2
C    4.3
D    2.4
E    3.5
F    7.6
G    5.7
EOD

set yrange[0:]
set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.8
set key noautotitle

# colors      red      green    blue     yellow   brown    grey     turquoise
myColors   = "0xff0000 0x00ff00 0x0000ff 0xffff00 0xa52a2a 0xcccccc 0x30e0d0"
myColor(i) = int(word(myColors,int(i+1)))
plot $Data u 0:2:(myColor($0)):xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var
### end of script
```

With an array it would look like this. It's shorter, but you have to specify the size of the array, whereas with a string you can simply add more colors. Replace the last block with this:

```
# colors             red       green     blue      yellow    brown     grey      turquoise
array myColors[7] = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0xffff00, 0xa52a2a, 0xcccccc, 0x30e0d0]
plot $Data u 0:2:(myColors[int($0+1)]):xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var
```

You can also define your linecolors via `linestyle` or `linetype` and an index, check `help linestyle` and `help linetype`.
You would get a similar result if you replace the last block with

```
set linetype 1 lc "red"
set linetype 2 lc "green"
set linetype 3 lc "blue"
set linetype 4 lc "yellow"
set linetype 5 lc "brown"
set linetype 6 lc "grey"
set linetype 7 lc "turquoise"
plot for [i=1:7] $Data every ::i-1::i-1 u (i):2:xtic(1) w boxes lt i
```

however, I would prefer the first variant, or maybe if at some point I will switch to gnuplot>=5.5, the following variant:

```
# for gnuplot>=5.5.0
myColors   = "red green blue yellow brown grey turquoise"
myColor(i) = rgbcolor(word(myColors,int(column(i)+1)))
plot $Data u 0:2:(myColor(0)):xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It is a chart bar. Each row of the file is a bar in the chart. Sorry for my mistake. I was misleading column with bars. I have fixed OP.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa then your question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54658674/7295599 or how is your case different?

Comment: Well, I don't want color names from datafile. I want to select a color form an auxiliary array.

Comment: With `using 0:5:(0.8):0:xtic(1)` and passing `myLinecolor(variable)` where `variable` I expect to be the row index it will throw `internal error : non-INTGR argument`

Comment: @MiguelGamboa would you be fine with using color hex-codes, e.g. `0xff0000` for red or has it to be color names? gnuplot5.5 has such a function.

Comment: colors or hex-codes are the same for me, since I can predfine those values in a constant like LINECOLORS of OP example

Comment: Thank you. Since op is about bars plot I would suggest you to remove the former part of your answer regarding other kind of plot and keep only the latter. I think there are other posts with similar answer to your first part.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa Done! Version with arrays added as well. Problem solved? Question answered?

Comment: Yes, it is! :up