# How can I use dynamic variable names in gnuplot with "with" notation?

Tags: arrays, loops, gnuplot, quotes

i want to use variables or arrays in plot command with for loop as follows

```
style[1]= "lines lt 4 lw 2"
style[2] = "points lt 3 pt 5 ps 2"
....

title[1]= "first title"
title[2]= "second title "
...
```

or

```
style="'lines lt 4 lw 2' 'points lt 3 pt 5 ps 2'"
title="'first title' 'second title'"
```

plot command

```
plot for [i=1:1000] 'data.txt' u 1:2 title title[i] with style[i]
plot for [i=1:1000] 'data.txt' u 1:2 title word(title,i) with word(style,i)
```

I was successful in the **title** part, but not in the **with** part. I realized that the problem was caused by quotes.

```
i=1
plot 'data.txt' u 1:2 title "first title" with "lines lt 4 lw 2"
```

When I use the array and **word** attributes, I get an error due to a quote error. I tried with **sprintf** but still no success.

```
sprintf("with %s", style'.i.')
```

I hope I could explain correctly. Any idea how I solve this? or how can i remove the quotes. Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I guess you cannot simply change the plotting style in a `plot for` loop, but you can change the linestyle. Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63699595/7295599
or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61692635/7295599 is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks @theozh.  I will carefully check the links you post. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to build a complete plot command as a string and `eval` it afterwards:

```
max_i = 2
array title[max_i]
array style[max_i]

style[1]= "lines lt 4 lw 2"
style[2] = "points lt 3 pt 5 ps 2"

title[1]= "first title"
title[2]= "second title"


cmd="plot NaN notitle"  # dummy for starting iteration
do for [i=1:max_i] {
   # append the explicit plot command
   cmd = sprintf("%s, sin(x*%d) title \"%s\" with %s", cmd, i, title[i], style[i])
}
print cmd  # just for checking the final plot command

eval cmd   # run plot command
```

It might be slow (or even not work at all) for 1000 lines. But I would be a bit scared of having 1000 lines and titles within a single diagram, anyhow.

Comment: Thanks @maij. Yesss this is almost exactly what I wanted. I guessed the solution was related to **sprintf** and **eval**. But i haven't been able to solve it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the styles you want to select from consist only of lines and/or points then you can do this by defining the corresponding `linestyle` and then selecting it by number.

```
set style line 1 lt 4 lw 2 pt 0               # lines only, no points
set style line 2 lt 3 lw 0.001 pt 5 ps 2      # points only, no lines
array Title[2] = ["style 1", "style 2"]

plot for [i=1:2] sin(x/i) with linespoints ls i title Title[i]
```

Note: It probably won't work to suppress the lines by setting lw to exactly 0, as many terminals interpret this as "thinnest possible line" rather than "no line".  So instead we set it to something very very thin that hopefully will not be visible.

[image]

If the styles you want to select from include something other than lines+points, then no I don't think it is possible to use this trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ethan. probably this method works for me. I learned that we cannot easily return a value under the plot command.